# Shared Base Class for numerous winforms UserControls?

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, user-controls, partial

This feels like I'm going to kick myself when I find the answer. I want a number of UserControls to share some properties (like ID) and Events (that is they will all raise the same event). I tried creating a BaseClass `UserControl` and then tried `Inherits BaseClass` on my UserControls. However, I get the error:

> Base class 'BaseClass' specified for Class `Viewer` cannot be
> different from the base class `UserControl` of one of its other
> partial types.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: For clarity, a bit of code. This hopefully illustrates how I would like it to work:

```
Public Class BaseUserControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Property ID
    Public Event ItemSelected()

End Class

Public Class Browser
    Inherits BaseUserControl

    Private Sub ButtonPressed() Handles Button1.click

        RaiseEvent ItemSelected()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class NavBar
    Inherits BaseUserControl

    Private Sub EnterKeyDown() Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

        RaiseEvent ItemSelected()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Main

    Dim WithEvents browser As Browser With {.id = 12}
    Dim WithEvents navbar As NavBar With {.id = 624}

    Public Sub New()

        Me.controls.add(browser)
        Me.controls.add(navbar)

    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectionInBrowser() Handles brower.ItemSelected
        'Do amazing stuff
    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectionInNavBar() Handles navbar.ItemSelected
        'Do amazing stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create your base class as a `UserControl`. E.g. name it `BaseUserControl`. Compile it. Then right click on the project or a folder in the project and click **Add** > **New Item**. Then select **Windows Forms** on the left hand side and  then **Inherited User Control (Windows Forms)**. Give it a name and click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. Now a dialog opens where you can select your `BaseUserControl`. Then click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Visual Studio does some magic for you. E.g. it overrides `Dispose` in the designer generated code. You could do it manually, but like this you get it right for free.

You can place controls on the `BaseUserControl`. They will be inherited and visible in the deriving user controls.

Note that you must change the modifier of the controls in the base user control to `Protected`, `Proteced Friend` or `Public` to enable them to be modified in the inheriting user control.

---

Example of inheritance. In `BaseUserControl` I placed two buttons `Button1` and `Button2` and made them `Protected` to make them visible in the derived classs. Then I double clicked on `Button1`. This creates a `Button1_Click` event handler. I changed its signature to

```
Public Class BaseUserControl
    Protected Overridable Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles Button1.Click

        MessageBox.Show($"Hello from {NameOf(BaseUserControl)}.{NameOf(Button1_Click)}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

i.e., make it `Protected Overridable`. This is not strictly necessary, but it allows you to override it in the descendants.

Saved and compiled and then opened `MyUserControl` where the two buttons are visible. Clicked on `Button2` which does not yet have a clicked event handler to create one.

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles Button2.Click

        MessageBox.Show($"Hello from {NameOf(MyUserControl)}.{NameOf(Button2_Click)}")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.Button1_Click(sender, e)
        MessageBox.Show($"Hello from {NameOf(MyUserControl)}.{NameOf(Button1_Click)}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see I also did override `Button1_Click`. `MyBase.Button1_Click(sender, e)` calls the original implementation from the `BaseUserControl`.

Then I placed `MyUserControl` on a Form and started the application. A click on `Button1` first shows:

> Hello from BaseUserControl.Button1_Click

and after closing the first message box by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>

> Hello from MyUserControl.Button1_Click

A click on `Button2` shows:

> Hello from MyUserControl.Button2_Click

Comment: Heh. As you were typing that Olivier, I was updating my post. Thanks for that - I'll give it a go, although thinking I'm giving up for the night as the Lord of all coding has been a right git today. Will feed back

Comment: Couldn't resist. Absolutely perfect answer @Olivier - thanks. Interesting stuff. You can place properties and controls in the BaseClass, but not Events. I'm sure there's some logic to that somewhere. I also had a UserControl that I'd already done a lot of work on. I just opened its designer.vb and changed the Inherits near the top from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` to my full BaseUserControl path + that did it! Thanks again.

Comment: You can place everything in the base class, even events.

Comment: Weird, that. When I did it last night I got an error (think compile) saying couldn't store events in a base class + reference them in one that inherits. However, after just amending the designer code rather than going through the menus route, I can't get it to reproduce that error. So I have TestEvent in my base class, but it's not exposed in my derived class. I'll have to look into this some more....

Comment: `Private` things are not visible in the derived class. They must be at least `Protected`, but can also be `Public` or `Protected Friend`.

Comment: Yeah - it was. So in the base class you have `Public Event TestEvent(str As String)` and in the derived class, you just can't raise event (e.g. using `RaiseEvent TestEvent("here")` - it just won't compile). Unusual

Comment: Create a public or protected method in the base class named `OnTestEvent` that raises the event. Then you can call this one in the derived class. [Step by Step: Event handling in VB.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5041/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-VB-NET).